# Получение записи при зависимости ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Когда забираю Sticker, в поле сообщения записываются все сообщения относящиеся к данному Sticker'у, а надо забрать только последнее сообщение

models.py

```
class Sticker(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='stickers')
    flags = models.ForeignKey(Flag, related_name='stickers')

class Messages(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    sticker = models.ForeignKey(Sticker, related_name='messages')
    attachment = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('date', 'text', 'id', 'sticker')

class StickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = MessageSerializer(Messages.objects.order_by('date')[0], many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sticker
        fields = ('id', 'board', 'flags', 'messages')
```

views.py

```
class Stickers(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )

    def get(self, request, board_id):
        stickers = Sticker.objects.get(board=board_id)
        serializer = StickerSerializer(stickers)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно только последнее сообщение, то попробуйте так

serializers.py

```
class StickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_message = MessageSerializer(source='messages.last', many=False)

class Meta:
    model = Sticker
    fields = ('id', 'board', 'flags', 'last_message')
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо, ваша версия работает, но я нашел еще 1 выход из ситуации:

```
class StickerSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
     def to_representation(self, obj):
         return {'id': obj.id,
                 'board': obj.board,
                 'flags': obj.flags,
                 'last_message': MessageSerializer(
                         obj.car_set.all().order_by('date')[0]).data}
```